# Settings value saved during run time is not changing from design in visual studio

Tags: c#, app-config, application-settings

At my settings file i have a parameter "Is_Running" and it value is set as 0

at run time i will check the value like below

```
if(Settings.Default.Is_Running == 0)
{
Settings.Default.Is_Running = 1;
Settings.Default.Save();
upload_file();
Settings.Default.Is_Running = 0;
Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Due to some reason i stopped the program in the middle of execution. Now the condition is always failing. So i checked value of `Is_Running` using a message box and it shows "1". I checked the app config file and it shows below

```
<setting name="Is_Running" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
```

Any idea why it still use "1"?

Comment: Why do you mean by "stopped the program in the middle of execution"?

Comment: its a windows service i stopped the service

Comment: In VS you change the *default* values of settings. Real settings are stored in the path `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\<CompanyName>\<AppName>\<version>\user.config`

Comment: @Dmitry thanks but for me it was inside `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile.......` can u post it as answer..i was searching for a solution for past 2 hrs

Comment: @Sachu Done. Couldn't you edit my answer to add the path in case of Windows Service, please?

Comment: @Dmitry done..at my local pc the path is said like u..at server level the path is as i mentioned in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS you change the *default* values of settings. Real settings are stored in the path `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\<CompanyName>\<AppName>\<v‌​ersion>\user.config` (for applications).

*Added by @Sachu.*
Since my application is windows service installed in server level, the path is little different. What I done is searched for `user.config` then got the file and path. Changed the value to `0` and it worked fine.

In my case the path is:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\<application_folder_name>
\<application_name>\<version>\user.config
```